# Telnet server -> backspace/delete not working

Tags: c#, protocols, telnet

I'm implementing a simple proof of concept Telnet server in C# and telnet to it via the windows built in telnet client.
I echo all non IAC data back to the client. However, I can't figure out how to get backspace/delete to work correctly. 
I tried several combinations acting on 'BS' from the telnet client:

- 'BS' (moves cursor back by one but doesn't delete character)
- 'BS''DEL' (same result as 'BS' only)
- 'BS''DEL''ESC[3~' (same result)

Can anyone please point me to what's the correct control sequence to backspace and remove the character from the screen?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: You could probably benefit greatly using a packet sniffer like Wireshark. Have Wireshark monitor outbound Telnet connections, telnet to a behaved server and watch what it sends back when back-spacing.

Comment: yes, if I had a telnet server to test this against :) Unfortunately I can't think of any that mimics the desired behavior and I have access to.

Comment: Then find a linux live installation that will run off a USB stick and will run a telnet server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just connected to a Cisco switch and traced how IOS is implementing it.
IOS is sending 'BS' 'SPACE' 'BS' on an incoming 'BS' from the client. So, that's how I implemented it now and works great.

Answer (score 7):

I was stuck trying to figure this out for ages but its actually extremely simple if echo is on. When a `\b` (backspace) is detected. You can send (through socket):

```
Socket.Send(new byte[] { 0x08, 0x20, 0x08 });
```

`0x08` sends the backspace, which is a non destructive backspace at it just moves the cursor to the left one. `0x20` sends a space which the deletes that character, and then the backspace again moving the cursor back to the left. Works like a charm!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Behavior of delete and backspace are dependent on the terminal emulation of the server.  Further, hitting backspace and or delete in the client may or may not send the actual backspace and delete keycodes to the server, depending on what it believes the emulation to be.  I don't believe there is a terminal agnostic command for moving back one character and removing the last character.  [Here's](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/backspace.html) a good discussion of the problem.

Finally, don't use the windows built in telnet client.  It sucks.  I prefer Van Dyke's [SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/), but if you don't want to spend money, [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a popular free client.

Comment: Well, as indicated in my post, I'm reacting on the client sending 'BS' (backspace) and tried to reply with different control sequences to achieve the desired behavior. I've read the article you posted and it says to do what I did. I don't want to use SecurCRT or PuTTY for this, which btw show the same behavior.

Comment: Your question leaves unclear how you're determining what's being sent.  Are you looking at debug information on the server side or simply relying on windows telnet to send BS when you hit the backspace key?

Comment: I'm looking at debug information and trace traffic with wireshark

Answer (score 1):

```
static uint8_t space = 0x20;
static uint8_t BS = 0x08;

if (ui8Char == 0x08)
{
if (i != 0) i--;
tcp_write(pState->pConnectPCB, &BS, 1, 1); 
tcp_write(pState->pConnectPCB, &space, 1, 1);
```

Its delete the data which you echo on your terminal and also in your buffer.
first check for backspace and decrement your buffer and then use BS and Space. Its work perfectly for Telnet. You donot have to change anything in teraterm or putty.